# TVS bidirectional diode not working

Tags: diodes, high-voltage, protection, tvs

10x bidirectional diodes [1.5KE400CA](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/1.5ke400ca-r0/bidirectional-tht-transil-diodes/taiwan-semiconductor/) in series, balanced, then the chain in parallel for DC line protection. Breakdown voltage 400V per diode. Still got 10kV+ voltage spikes (picture below, x100000 attenuation). Why?

[image]

---

Edit:

Pulse shape and duration varies greatly (another example pictured below).
Rise time for the first oscillation: 10-20 ns.
Estimated inductance: ~20 uH.

[image]

The negative peak is timed at 8 us, way over the clamping voltage (7kV peak and 4kV clamping voltage) and TVS diodes still not conducting.

---

Edit 2:
Equivalent circuit pictured below. D3 undergoes catastrophic failure on higher voltages. (Scope readings shown here ~ 300V; real working conditions ~3kV)

[image]

---

Edit 3:
Equivalent circuit, measurements by precision shunt.

[image]

[image]

---

Edit 4:
Hardware set-up. Power electronics module.

[image]

Comment: What does the input pulse look like? Rise time? Series impedance? And, very important, what is the estimated inductance of your series assembly?

Comment: Looks like measurement error with ringing.  Show your layout and probe methods and ground length

Comment: Hi. It's a pulsed DC application, resembling a short circuit. Voltage drop on a precision shunt gives the same pulse shape. So it's just a shunt and x10 attenuation scope probe.

Comment: Show a detailed diagram of your test setup if you want proper help.

Comment: I have read this three times. I still have no idea what the energy source is for the spike or where or how you have connected your probes. But a 20mV pulse can sometimes couple into an oscilloscope via channel-to-channel crosstalk, or directly into the probe wires. I suggest adding a photograph of your test setup. And disconnect any unused probes from your oscilloscope.

Comment: Hello. The capacitor discharges via D2 SCR, through Load1 and those voltage peaks are too energetic for the rectifying bridge charging the capacitor.

Comment: Does L2 represent a parasitic element, or is it an actual inductor that was installed deliberately? It seems that the TVS should be installed closer to the component that is failing, if possible. But I am a bit outside my element with such high voltages, honestly. But just applying basic circuit stuff, L2 will certainly prevent the TVS current from increasing rapidly. When the SCR fires, there is an energetic transient. it would be easy to get a few 100 mV coupling onto the oscilloscope probe. If that is happening, your readings might be wholly bogus.

Comment: You have to prevent any inductance between the source of the high voltage peak and the TVS, this must be as short as possible. Where do you impact your high peak voltage? The L2 prevents a fast rise of the voltage at the TVS, so the L2 became a counter induction and a negative voltage is induces when the TVS breaks through. Do you balance the TVS diodes with resistors, of which size? I suspect the load is 2 mega Ohms or really milli ohms?

Comment: @mkeith L2 is deliberately installed for slowing the TVS current and get high energy MOV+GDS (not shown) components in conduction mode. The TVS would certainly fail to absorb/divert the transient energy by itself. Why are the readings incorrect?

Comment: @Tom Kuschel TVS balanced with 470 kOhm resistors. Load is ~20 mili ohms and peak current ~75 kA at full power. I will remove L2 and relocate TVS near D3. But i'm almost certain it will explode on  avalanche breakdown.

Comment: If the 3 Gigohm resistor has a series inductance, or a shunt capacitance, or if the 30k resistor does, that will mean that your attenuator has a frequency response characteristic that is not flat. That can introduce oddities in the response which are not part of the signal you are trying to observe, but are artefacts of the attenuator itself.

Comment: Also, if there are fast trasnient events going on with high dV/dt and dI/dt, then it is easy for signal to couple directly to the oscilloscope. The signal you are looking at is only 100mV. That could be spurious (not real). You could be trying to debug something that isn't actually part of your signal.

Comment: The other thing that is missing is an explanation of why you have any voltage overshoot in the first place. A capacitor discharging into a resistor does not automatically have voltage overshoot, although with L1 and L2, the possibility of overshoot is introduced. If there are parasitic inductances that cannot be removed, then you may just have to deal with the overshoot. But so far, I don't see a good explanation of what is going on in the first place. Barring that, any effort at remediation will be hit and miss.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for the explanation regarding possible measurements error, I will look further into it.
Measurements on a 100 uOhm (SHUNT - Edit 3) series resistor yielded approximately similar results (peaks).
 L1 is mandatory, as the LOAD needs a longer pulse. Removing L2, relocating the TVS module across D3 and using more potent TVS diodes could solve the problem or it is just patchwork?

Comment: http://www.caltestelectronics.com/ctitem/18-probe-oscilloscope-high-voltage/CT4026

Comment: From the picture I think I see some nice big induction loops that maybe shouldn't be there in the first place. To prevent ringing and voltage spikes during switching, the layout should be such that parasitic inductances are as small as you can possibly make them. This circuit suggests you (unwillingly) did the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traces that you are capturing on the oscilloscope are not very compelling in terms of being true signals. When trying to measure small signals arising from high dV/dt or di/dt events, it is easy to deceive yourself, because small amounts of the pulse energy can couple into the oscilloscope through an unintentional path.

In particular, this circuit has a voltage divider formed by a 3 Giga-ohm resistor and a 30k resistor. If any energy can couple directly to the divider node, the scope will pick it up, and you will think it represents a real and true signal. Because of the divider factor, this mistake can cause you to dramatically over-estimate the actual voltage at the top of the divider. High voltage probes exist which would allow you to probe the input voltage safely and directly. You could also reduce the divider factor so that the input signal is more like several volts instead of 100mV. If the signal scales accordingly, it is more likely to be real.

A similar concern applies to your shunt measurement. Any voltage which couples to the oscilloscope input will cause you to estimate a large current (because the shunt is so small). One workaround for this would be to use a current probe to measure the current more directly. Current probes are available which can clamp around any conductor in the circuit. For example, see the picoscope product TA167 (2000 Amp current probe). If possible, a slightly larger shunt might help, too, because it will increase the signal amplitude.

Another idea, as long as your shunt is very low resistance, and as long as the anticpated voltage across the shunt is not higher than the oscilloscope maximum input voltage, you can use 50 Ohm coaxial cable instead of a scope probe. Then configure the oscilloscope input to 50 Ohms. This will somewhat reduce the voltage amplitude of any pulse energy coupling into the oscilloscope (but not the signal). If you get a dramatically different reading when you use 50 Ohm cable and 50 Ohm input impedance compared to 10x attenuating oscilloscope probe and high input impedance, then most likely you are getting some form of direct coupling.

Other ideas: Leave the probe attached to the oscilloscope, but do not attach the oscilloscope leads to the circuit under test. Run the experiment. Do you see a similar signal? Whatever signal you see on the oscilloscope under these conditions is NOT getting into the oscilloscope through a conductive path. That is something to think about.

I have had occasion to measure a lot of things so far in my career. I have not yet had to measure kV signals, but I have had to measure signals on current shunts in the presence of relatively rapid dV/dt signals, and it is challenging. The test setup really matters. The most accurate results can be obtained by using expensive active probes or dedicated differential probes with very short leads. Both of those are things you can consider purchasing or renting for your testing. The test setup is absolutely critical.

As far as TVS protection goes, it is generally best to put the protection as close as possible to the item being protected. If the TVS blows up, that just means you need a bigger TVS. You never want an inductor between a TVS and the protected item.

But the NUMBER ONE thing you need to figure out is WHY do you get a voltage overshoot (or do you really get a voltage overshoot?). Is it just cable inductance? So during the initial current spike, the cable inductance stores energy in the cable, and then the current cannot just stop, so voltage overshoots. That is common when a power supply is connected to a low ESR cap with a long wire. But in your case it is a bit perplexing because how do you get overshoot into a 20mOhm resistive load? The load is basically a short circuit already.

It might help if you are able to attach a picture of your setup or a full schematic of the real circuit that shows all parts and indicates wire lengths between the parts.

One other thought. If D3 is the part that is failing, it would be a good idea to probe at D3/C2 as directly as possible. As previously noted, your Giga-ohm resistor could be contributing to measurement error. If you can get a high-voltage probe across C2 and see what is happening, that would be very useful. Running the circuit at reduced voltages seems to be possible. So if you run it at 100V, what is the highest voltage you see at C2/D3? Maybe you can use a less exotic probe (I believe quite a few probes can handle well above 100V directly).

Comment: Old photo (Edit 4), main components are still the same. It is a High Energy Pulsed Power Supply - pulsed DC, discharge time (from microseconds to 2-3 ms max) is altered by L1 inductance.
D2 and L1 have to withstand a maximum of 75 kA for that period. The load represents a relatively controlled short-circuit in different configurations.

Comment: Command and controll circuits are not an issue, as the transient energy is absorbed by the rectifier bridge (D3) charging C2. I've tried to protect the bridge with 12x serial diodes (300mA, 16kV each), to no avail either. The scope readings almost certainly are incorrect, but the transient is of at least tens of kV magnitude, quite energetic also ( first diode explodes ). Could this be the standard issue you mentioned about low ESR cap and long wires?
 
Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: This is a good example of "how not to design a high energy pulse generator" with excessive stray inductance and no controlled impedances and no specs in the question.

Comment: Is D3 blowing up while the capacitor is charging? Prior to now, I had assumed that it was blowing up after the SCR fires, during the discharge event. If you are not sure because it all happens at once, it may be worthwhile to temporarily separate out the entire discharge circuit so that you can tell what is causing the failure.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist Hello. The busbars need to be shorter, smaller section? When designing the PPS I had in mind mainly the clearing and creepage distance recommended for the capacitor  and low resistivity.

Comment: @mkeith It explodes after the SCR fires. I could separate the circuit for debugging.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist I knew there will be problems with inductance, but problems coming from the inductor L1. I'm not a professional.

Comment: Every path must be low inductance  to 20 mOhm load.  Who made this? What is the purpose?  V= LdI/dt and avalanche breakdown dt goes to near zero

Comment: Here I see 20 mΩ load from Cap with ESR=10 mΩ and meanwhile too high impedance at resonant f thus false load and false measurement.  What is real purpose?

Comment: Tony, please keep in mind that the forum is to help people with questions. Try to provide the OP with a path forward that leads to enlightenment or solves the immediate problem.

Comment: LOAD was not measured, there are different conductive materials used to "short" the power supply. I see now that it's easy to measure low resistances, it will be done. Yes, i think dt is too small so V is way to high, i presume that's the reason why the rectifier bridge blows up. TVS diodes were added to solve that problem. All the busbar segments and capacitor charger wires have inductance of a few hundred nH (calculated). I presume that's  also too much.

Comment: So, higher value on L1 would increase dt, thus it would be beneficial? Or i'm getting this wrong?